# Tomcat unable to start even after changing the port number

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using window 7 os, and i have installed tomcat 6, it is working fine. But i have configured new workspace which is developed using "Dynamic web module 3.0",so i am unable run this by using tomcat 6,because of this i have downloaded tomcat7 zip file and configured tomcat7 to new workspace,but when i run i was getting an error as

"Port 8009 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)"

So i have changed the tomcat default port number in conf/server.xml

`

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />



<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />



<Connector port="4018" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

`

After changing the tomcat port, i have restarted the eclipse and tried to run the project with tomcat 7 server then also i am getting the same error.
"Port 8009 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
"

So please help me out how to fix this issue.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13185498/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to verify if the port is in use by other services. There are third part softwares that you can use to scan those ports or you can use netstat.

Second check if you have missed any kind of TomCat dependencies in your operating system. With other software such as XAMPP, WAMP they depend on some libraries like Visual C++ Redistributable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure all thoses ports in Eclipse by using the "Servers" view.

Go to the Menu
 "Window"-->"Show view"-->"Other..." and search for the "Servers" view. Press OK.

In that view, all your Tomcat instances are listed (and they display the application they contain).

Double-click on your Tomcat instance to display the Tomcat configuration editor: there you will find a "Ports" section that allows you to easily modify those port values. Once changed, press "Save" and restart your Tomcat.