# Eclipse can't start Tomcat with option : takes control of Tomcat installation

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Luna. To work with Eclipse and Tomcat together followed this steps.

1) Installed Tomcat using : sudo apt-get install tomcat7

2) From eclipse `tomcat start and stop` works fine with below image radio button 1 option (double click server in eclipse). But with option 1 browser find 404 to visit `http://localhost:8080/`

3) Apply the option 2 :Use Tomcat installation(Take control of Tomcat installation)

like the image below

---

[image]

---

**It does not even start the server with radio option 2. When I tried to start server find error like this**

[image]

---

I have tried to find solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start). Applied this but it does not worked for me.

```
<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

Also tried to apply from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185498/starting-tomcat-server-7-at-localhost-has-encountered-a-prob) and changed port. but not worked.

Also Executed option like this :

```
cd~/workspaceEclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
rm org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
rm org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
rm org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
rm org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo service tomcat7 stop
sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 disable
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf conf
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 log
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/tomcat7/conf
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/common common
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/server server
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/shared shared
```

**Can anyone know solution of this problem ?**

Comment: You are having file permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recomment do avoid using eclipse with the Ubuntu repository Tomcat.

Unless you run eclipse as root you will not be able to publish your configuration.

Download tomcat manually, unpack in your home folder and you should get rid of your problem

Comment: what is roor? did you mean root?@Luca Putzu

Comment: @Aman: sure... sorry for the typo. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are having file permission issue.
Just go to `/usr/share/tomcat` by the user you logged in and give recursive read+ write permission to sub-directories for the user by which you running eclipse.