# Tomcat doesn't start from eclipse on startup : Several ports (8005, 8080) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, server

Everyday when I start my computer, and then attempt to start my tomcat server in eclipse , it gives me following error.

> starting tomcat v7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem[image: Ports busy error]

I have googled for this issue but whatever I got was temporary solution/i.e killing apache
`sudo kill $(ps -aef | grep apache| awk '{print $2}')`
this solves the problem but not permanantly.
after entering above command on terminal , I start tomcat from eclipse and then my tomcat server starts.

but I have to enter this command daily before starting my work and also whenever I restart my PC,is there any other permanant solution which can directly allow me to start my tomcat from eclipse.

I have tried adding and removing tomcat server also deleting the server and adding it back,but this doesnt solve the problem.

FYI : I am using ubuntu 14.04,eclipse mars,tomcat version 7.

Comment: change the ports by double clicking the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["starting Tomcat server 7 at localhost has encountered a prob"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185498/starting-tomcat-server-7-at-localhost-has-encountered-a-prob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the port numbers in server configuration.you should change all the three port number is show in bellow image.

[image]

Comment: Or alternatively, change the port numbers of the Tomcat that is running at the OS level by changing its conf/server.xml .

Answer (score 1):

also you can try to disable the autostart on boot, and launch tomcat from eclipse.

`sudo systemctl disable tomcat7.service`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have already installed tomcat (or other application) that used 8005 or 8080 port.

You can find that application by command:

`sudo netstat -lntp | grep 8080`

`sudo netstat -lntp | grep 8005`

If you not use that application, just remove it :

`sudo apt-get remove APP`

P. S. Also you can just run tomcat from eclipse on other (not 8005 and 8080) ports.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to determine the service running on these ports and just disable autostarttup at boottime instead of removing the whole app?